# Find the expression of the tetrahedron passing through these points: $P_0=(0,0,0),P_1=(a,0,0),P_2=(0,b,0),P_3=(0,0,c) \qquad a,b,c>0$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Finding the plane passing through $P_1,P_2,P_3$:

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
x-a & y & z \\
-a & b & 0 \\
-a & 0 & c
\end{pmatrix}=-a(-b \ z)+c ((x-a) \ b+ a \ y)=cb \ x+ac \ y +ab \ z-abc
$$

So, the expression is:
$$T=\{ cb \ x+ac \ y +ab \ z \le abc, x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0 \}$$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: I'd write the first inequality as $x/a+y/b+z/c\le1$.